# Array Manipulation from HackerRank

Tags: java, arraylist

I am getting error stating **Terminated due to timeout** for larger inputs when using ArrayList, for smaller one it works fine.

I watched solutions where they were using **PREFIX SUM ALGORITHM** and 2-dimension array as parameter. Can we not use **ArrayList** as parameter instead of array?

Here is the question ---

Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for each operation add a value to each of the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in your array.

For example, the length of your array of zeros . Your list of queries is as follows:

```
a b k
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1
```

Add the values of between the indices and inclusive:

```
index -> 1 2 3  4  5 6 7 8 9 10
        [0,0,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0]
        [3,3,3, 3, 3,0,0,0,0, 0]
        [3,3,3,10,10,7,7,7,0, 0]
        [3,3,3,10,10,8,8,8,1, 0]


The largest value is returned after all operations are performed.
Here the output will be 10;
```

My code is

```
public static long arrayManipulation(int n, List<List<Integer>> queries) {
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(n+1, 0));

        //PREFIX SUM 
        for(int i = 0; i<queries.size(); i++){
            int a = queries.get(i).get(0)-1;
            int b = queries.get(i).get(1);
            int k = queries.get(i).get(2);
            
            arr.set(a, arr.get(a)+k);
            arr.set(b, arr.get(b)-k);
        }
        
         long max=0;
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            arr.set(i, arr.get(i)+arr.get(i-1));
            if(arr.get(i)>max)
            {
                max=arr.get(i);
            }
         } 
        
        
        Collections.sort(arr);
        return arr.get(n);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?  If Hackerrank lets you ArrayList instead of Array?  Does not really seem like a relevant question for this site.  Though, I am pretty sure when HackerRank asks you to use an _array_, you use an _array_ not a list

Comment: Hackerrank enters ArrayList as the parameter for the function but i m getting timeout error in few test cases. I have provided the link for the question.

Comment: Your for loop probably is not ending and times out. Check the logic in the forloop and see if it exits correctly